# Unable to load PHP file into a inner HTML Div created dynamically with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, file, dynamic, innerhtml

I am able to load a .php file into a div simply by using `<?php include("file.php") ?>`
The file can have php, javascript, html and plain text in it and it still works great.

I am NOT able to load the file into a Div I created dynamically with javascript if the file has script tags in it.

***NOTE: I am updating the code as I make progress***

**index.php**

The first Div works great and loads the test.php file with no issues.

```
<div id="phpDiv"
    style="
    position:absolute; 
    top: 50px; 
    left: 50px;
    height: 200;
    width: 300;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;"> 
        This is the phpDiv  <br>
        <?php include("test.php"); ?>
</div>
```

The Second Div created dynamically will not load the file if it has script tags in it

```
<script>
    var javascriptDiv = document.createElement('div');
    javascriptDiv.setAttribute('id', 'javascriptDiv');
    javascriptDiv.style.position = 'absolute';  
    javascriptDiv.style.top = 350;
    javascriptDiv.style.left = 50;
    javascriptDiv.style.height = 200;
    javascriptDiv.style.width = 300;
    javascriptDiv.style.background = '#CCCCCC'; //so we can see that the DIV was created

    <?php  
            //must have http:// in it to load php stuff
            //will not load files with <script> tags
            $file = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/Debug/test.php');

            //Trim the string and remove new lines.
            $file = trim($file);
            $file = str_replace("\n", "", $file);
            $file = str_replace("\r", "", $file);

            echo "javascriptDiv.innerHTML = \"This is the javascriptDiv <br>\";  ";  
            echo "javascriptDiv.innerHTML += '". $file ."';";
    ?>

    document.body.appendChild(javascriptDiv); //Display the Window
</script>
```

**test.php**  <-the file i'm trying to load

```
<?php echo "php works <br>"; ?>
<script> alert('javascript works'); </script>
<a> html works </a><br><br>

and extra spaces and plain text work fine as well
```

Comment: What does test.php look like? Are you escaping the `'` in PHP? Is everything in the file on one line, no line breaks, or are you chunking and concatenating that content for JS?

Comment: If the browser is seeing something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/W3k7P/ and it doesn't work, it's because you can't span variables across two lines like that.

Comment: Your DIV content would need to look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/W3k7P/1/ Note the string concatenation for each line, with each line quoted.

Comment: what does your rendered source code look like? What does the Javascript console say? These would both be very useful to know :]

Comment: Ok things are looking better. Now the only problem i'm having is the dynamic Div loading files with script tags in them. It will load everything else.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it doesn't work because you use single quotes into your single quotes statement setting your innerHTML.

```
<?php echo "php works <br>"; ?>
<script> alert("javascript works"); </script>
<a> html works </a><br><br>
```

Edit:

You can try to strip newlines automatically like so:

```
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('test.php', false, $context);
$file = str_replace( "\r\n", "", $file );
```

put $file into your innerHTML

Comment: if i strip all but the first line from test.php, it will then load.

Comment: Also i don't know if it is possible to use javascript in a innerHTML statement :)

Comment: You can use HTML in an inner**HTML** assignment. It sounds like it's a multiline quoting problem.

Comment: He should test this by making it without newlines, then i can tell him how to strip newlines :)

Comment: Please don't guess what the answer is. If you want to try to narrow down what the problem is, use the comments under the question. `:)`

Comment: Nah its simply a good awnser, maybe not fully awnser. Because as you can see it is a quote problem, as i stated.

Comment: even just two line of html don't work  <a>text line 1</a> <a>test line 2>

Comment: So you would have to strip your newlines too, also make sure you make quotes like i did!

Comment: OK..  things work ok with no new lines except for the javascript.  <script> tags kill it.

Comment: That fixes the HTML lines but it kills the php line outputting  "; ?>

Comment: Care to explain why you downvoted an answer from two days ago?

Comment: You should get a PHP output when you try to reach the same page via HTTP, maybe try this :)

Comment: So I guess no comment? It's poor form to downvote someone out of spite.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see this code . I was successful with it . Create your index.php code and put the Jquery file in that directory.Download it from here http://jquery.com/download/.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>load demo</title>
<style>
body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; }
</style>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<b>Successful Response (should be blank):</b>
<div id="success"></div>
<b>Error Response:</b>
<div id="error"></div>
<script>
var browser=navigator.userAgent;
//if (browser.lastIndexOf("Chrome")>=5)
{
alert("ok");
$("#success").load("index.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
if (status == "error") {
var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
$("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
}
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```